# How to convert from BYTE array to CString in MFC?

Tags: c++, string, mfc

How can I convert a BYTE array in a CString in MFC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this - for eg: - If 'x' is your Byte array then -

```
BYTE x[5]; 
x[0] = 'A'; 
x[1] = 0; 
x[2] = 'B'; 
x[3] = 'C'; 
x[4] = 0; 

CString str( (LPCSTR) &x, sizeof(x) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BYTE x[5]; x[0] = 'A'; x[1] = 'B'; x[2] = 'C'; x[3] = 'D'; x[4] = '0';

CString str = TEXT("");
CString s;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    str.Format(L"%C",x[i]);
    s += str;
}

AfxMessageBox(s);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
BYTE packet[IN_PACKET_SIZE];
CString Text;
Text.Format((LPCWSTR)L"%d hours \t%d minutes \t%d seconds \t%d °C", packet[0], packet[1], packet[2], packet[3]);
```

Comment: Please also add some explanation to your answer.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22112676)